# Lock Screen Wallpaper

Tags: 5.1-lollipop

I don't know how to have a lock screen wallpaper on my phone. I'm using an Android 5.1 Lollipop (Omega HD3, Cherry Mobile). Where can i find the setting to set my lock screen wallpaper on my device?

Comment: while setting wallpaper in android, it will ask whether to set both, or home screen , lock screen seperately .

Comment: If your default method doesn't work then you can try installing apps from PlayStore that changes your lock screen wallpapers.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the gallery, find the picture you would like to set as Lockscreen wallpaper.
When u have the picture opened, in the menu ( 3 dots - usually) there is `Set as..`

Just click it and it will ask you for " `Set as Homescreen wallpaper` / `Set as Homescreen wallpaper and lockscreen wallpaper`  /  `Set as lockscreen wallpaper`"

Now select your option.